# curl_file_create from file resource using mongo gridfs

Tags: php, curl

I have files inside MongoDb stored as binary data, I can get the binary data and if I `var_dump` it it'll show it as `Resource #1000` or similar. Now I need to send this file via curl to other server for processing, however `curl_file_create` wants file path.

What should I do if my file has no path?

I have tried putting it inside like so but with no success.

```
private function sendToApi($resource, $name) {
    $cFile = curl_file_create($resource, 'application/pdf', $name);
    $postData = ['file' => $cFile];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username' . ':' . 'pass');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.endpoint.com/process/pdf');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: multipart/form-data']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $obj = json_decode($res);
    return $obj;
}
```

#### Error

PHP Warning:  curl_file_create() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given.

Answer (score 0):

To get gridFS binary data use the method "getBytes()" http://php.net/manual/en/mongogridfsfile.getbytes.php

```
$cFile = curl_file_create($resource->getBytes(), 'application/pdf', $name);
```

Comment: Yea but the bytes are not the filename. I think curl wants to create file by reading path from the disk so passing bytes is not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create file as temp file and use it.

```
$tmp = tmpfile();
fwrite($tmp, $content);
fseek($tmp, 0);
$meta = stream_get_meta_data($tmp);
$cFile = curl_file_create($meta['uri'], 'application/pdf', $name);
$post = ['file' => $cFile];
```